Limit Client Applications' Access at API Endpoints
I’m seeking advice on how to limit client applications from accessing certain endpoints/resources in a Mule API. The use case aligns with what's outlined in this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001116921&type=1. I’m planning to implement this restriction at the Experience Layer, where multiple client applications are invoking the same EL layer API.
In all the EL layer APIs, we have the OpenId Connect access token enforcement policy enabled, with Azure AD as the Client provider.
According to the article, one solution to achieve this is by developing a custom policy. However, the policy used is Client ID Enforcement policy. It also suggests using another policy that allows for Authentication and Authorization, such as using OAuth. How can we implement this with Azure OAuth, given that we use the client credentials grant type for OAuth?
Additionally, would it be better to create custom scopes in Azure and use them in the OpenId Connect access token enforcement policy? Is this approach feasible?
I would appreciate your insights.

Don't ask multiple questions into one. Open different questions.

The article mentions using Client ID to validate the authorization. You can use whatever you want that the policy has access.
The documentation of the OpenID Connect OAuth 2.0 Token Enforcement Policy say that you can expose some headers with information that you can use for the clientIdExpression expression:

Configuring the Expose Headers Option
If you configured the Expose Headers option in the policy and if the application (for example, out-of-the-box proxies) uses the HTTP requester, the properties are redirected to the backend as headers.
For each field, the original request to the protected resource is enriched with the HTTP headers using the format: X-AGW- + <key>=<value>. For the example response from the previous section, the following headers are added:
X-AGW-uid=john.doe
X-AGW-mail=john.doe@example.com
X-AGW-token_type=Bearer

The propagated properties do not include the scope, and exp objects and arrays.

Note that the last sentence says that scopes are explicitly excluded.
So instead of validating clientIds you could use the user id or the email. Example: #[attributes.headers['X-AGW-mail']].
